# SIP SEER calculation questions

Tags: sip

My team & I are trying to capture the SEER health of UA3 based on the Invites from UA1. Due to the design of the system we get quite a few Response/CallEnds from UA4.

Based on the [RFC 6076](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6076#section-4.7) definition and explanation we know what to do with A.

My Question is for B & C

1. should B count in the numerator as a positive?
2. should B & C count in the denominator?
3. should both B & C be ignored from the Equation altogether?

Looking for Logical & Practical solution (even if those don't concur) to present to the Team.

[SIP SEER System setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRJ7w.png)

Numerator= # of INVITE Requests w/ associated 200, 480, 486, 600, or 603

Denominator = (Total # of INVITE Requests) - (# of INVITE Requests w/ 3XX Response)

Looking forward to your responses. Please Advice.

Thanks.

Not Applicable. This is an academic exercise.